# Selecting the latest order

Tags: sql

I need to select the data of all my customers with the records displayed in the image. But I need to get the most recent record only, for example I need to get the order # E987 for John and E888 for Adam. As you can see from the example, when I do the select statement, I get all the order records.

[image]

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Use the "Edit" link to add the code//errors as text to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the specific database, so I'll answer with a generic solution.

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by order_date desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `row_number`.

```
Select * from 
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date desc) as rn
  From your_table t) t
 Where rn = 1
```

Or you can use `not exists` as follows:

```
Select * 
  From yoir_table t
 Where not exists
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where t.customer_id = tt.custome_id
           And tt.order_date > t.order_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a subquery that finds the last order date.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM yoir_table t
JOIN (SELECT tt.custome_id, 
      MAX(tt.order_date) MaxOrderDate
      FROM yoir_table tt
      GROUP BY tt.custome_id) AS tt
ON t.custome_id = tt.custome_id
   AND t.order_date  = tt.MaxOrderDate
```